# PYTHON ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image' хотя модуль установлен

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу импортировать компонент image, установил и импортировал:

```
import image
text = "Hello, PIL!!!"
color = (0, 0, 120)
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 50), color)
imgDrawer = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
imgDrawer.text((10, 20), text)
img.save("pil-basic-example.png")
```

обшарил весь google и решение не нашел.
P.S. у меня кастомный путь установки: A:\Python\

Comment: Вы импортируете image, а использовать пытаетесь Image. Это не одно и то же. Ну и вам нужен Image из модуля PIL, а не просто Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо

```
import image
```

написать

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
```

Comment: К сожелению нет. Такой вопрос уже я находил и я бы не создавал этот вопрос если бы я нашел это в гугле.
Снова такая же ошибка
`
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named PIL
'

*может ли питон не найти модуль если у него нестандартный путь установки?

Comment: Надо посмотреть, что в переменной среды `path` записано. Возможно стоит прописать туда путь к установленному питону.

Comment: Это как? Я просто день назад начал изучать python.

Comment: Проблему с image я решил.. Но появилось следующая, теперь не работает PIL

Comment: Как именно не работает?

Comment: Опять же no module found PIL
Это решилось установкой python в папку по стандарту, наверное это баг...